# Drupal 7 dynamic multisite

Tags: web, drupal-7

Can anyone advice me on if it is possible to create a Drupal 7 multisite where each multisite is created dynamically as the result of creating a user of a certain role on the parent site?

Answer (score 0):

it is posible, if not very easy to accomplish. Drupal already provides tools to create and duplicate sites with drush commands (take a look at drush make).

You should search for inspiration on [aegir](http://community.aegirproject.org) which is a drupal distribution that manages drupal sites (can create, clone and backup drupal sites).

Comment: +1 http://mig5.net/content/introduction-aegir-hosting-system should provide a handy if dated overview of Aegir's innards.